# Solve an initial value problem using the directional derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

In my notes there is the following example of solving an initial value problem using the directional derivative.

The problem is the following:

$$u_t(x,t)=u_x(x,t), x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0 \\ u(x,0)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$$

We do the following:

$$u_t(x,t)-u_x(x,t)=0 \\ \left (u_x(x,t), u_t(x, t)\right ) \cdot \frac{(-1,1)}{\sqrt{2}}=0$$

$\overrightarrow{v}=\left (-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right )$

> *Reminder*:
>
> Directional Derivative: 
>        $v=(a,b)$, unit $|v|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1$ 
>        $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{v}}(x_0)=\nabla u(x_0) \cdot   v=\frac{d}{dt}u(x_0+tv)|_{t=0}=(u_x(x_0), u_y(x_0)) \cdot  
>  (a,b)=au_x+bu_y$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\overrightarrow{v}}}u(x,t)=0 \text{ When we are moving at the direction of } \overrightarrow{v}, u \text{ doesn't change. }$$

[image]

$$h(s)=u((x,t)+sv) \Rightarrow h'(s)=\nabla u((x,t)+sv) \cdot v \\ \text{ From the Mean Value Theorem we have that } \exists \xi \text{ in the intervall } 0,s : \\ h(s)=h(0)=(s-0)h'(\xi) \\ \text{ So, } u((x,t)+sv-u(x,t)=(s-0) \nabla u((x,t)+\xi v) \cdot v=0$$

So, $\exists \phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable

$u(x,t)=\phi(x+t)$

For $t=0 \Rightarrow u(x,0)=\phi(x) \Rightarrow \phi(x)=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

$u(x,t)=f(x+t), x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0$

$$$$

Could you explain to me this method??

How did we get that $u(x,t)=\phi(x+t)$ ??

$$$$

**EDIT:**

To solve an initial value problem as the above one, we do the following:

We are looking for the unit $\overrightarrow{v}$ such that $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{v}} \cdot \overrightarrow{v}=0$.

That means that $u$ is constant at the direction of $\overrightarrow{v}$.

Is it correct so far??

I haven't understood what we do next do find the solution... Could you explain it to me??

Answer (score 1):

You have that $(1,-1)\cdot\nabla u(x,t)=0$. This means that $u$ is constant on lines parallel to $(1,-1)$. Since the line connecting $(x,t)$ to $(x+t,0)$ is parallel to $(1,-1)$ we know that
$$
u(x,t)=u(x+t,0)=f(x+t)
$$
Check out [The Method of Characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics).

Comment: Why does it stand that the line connecting $(x,t)$ to $(x+t,0)$ is parallel to $(1,-1)$ ?? @robjohn

Comment: I got stuck right now... What relation does $\overrightarrow{v}$ have with the characteristics?? @robjohn

Comment: The difference of the points is $(x+t,0)-(x,t)=(t,-t)$. That is parallel to $(1,-1)$.

Comment: The characteristic curves are the lines parallel to $(1,-1)$. $\vec{v}=\left(-\frac{\sqrt2}2, \frac{\sqrt2}2\right )$ is parallel to $(1,-1)$.

Comment: With $(1,-1)$ we mean a vector not a point , right?? 
$$$$ 
So, in general the characteristic curves are the lines parallel to $v=(a,b)$ ?? @robjohn

Comment: In general, characteristic curves need not be lines. In the case of constant coefficient, first order differential equations, they are lines.

Comment: Yes. Since we are talking about parallel lines, $(1,-1)$ is a vector.

Comment: So, because $u$ is constant at the direction of $\overrightarrow{v}$, so at the direction of the characteristics( are the charactistics $x-t=c$ ??) , do we conclude that $u(x,t)=\phi(c)=\phi(x-t)$ ?? @robjohn

Comment: The characteristic curves are $x+t=c$. This line is in the direction of $(1,-1)$.

Comment: Do we find the characteristics as followed?? 
$$u_t-u_x=0 \Rightarrow \left (\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\right )u=0  $$ The solution is of the form $\phi(x+t)$ so the characteristics are $x+t=c$. Is this correct??   @robjohn

Comment: We have $$\partial_vu =v_x\partial_xu+v_t\partial_tu$$ and $$0=\partial_xu-\partial_tu$$ To make $\partial_vu=0$, we want $v=(1,-1)$

Comment: I edited my last comment... Could you tell me if it is correct now??

Comment: It works, but you might find it difficult to say what the form of the solution is when dealing with non-constant coefficient equations, etc. Remember that $v\cdot\nabla u=0$ says that $v$ is perpendicular to $\nabla u$.

Comment: Having found that $v=(1,-1)$ what do we do, in genera, to find the solution?? I got stuck right now... @robjohn

Comment: To solve an initial value problem as the above one, we do the following: 

We are looking for the unit $\overrightarrow{v}$ such that $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{v}} \cdot \overrightarrow{v}=0$. 

That means that $u$ is constant at the direction of $\overrightarrow{v}$. 

Is it correct so far?? 

I haven't understood what we do next do find the solution... Could you explain it to me??

Comment: Recall that on a path $(x,t)$ with a given $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ we have $$\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t} =\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$ Thus, if $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$$ then $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}=0$ when $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=-1$. That is, $u$ is constant on paths where $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=-1\iff x+t=c$.